# Real-time Markerless Motion capturing using normal webcam

Tags: augmented-reality, motion-detection

Is it possible to do "Markerless motion capturing" using a normal webcam, in real time? Are there any Open source frameworks available?

I need to construct a 3d model which will be animated using the captured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with [The Artvertiser](http://theartvertiser.com) (full source code available at the link).

You could also look at using the [Ferns library](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/software/ferns/index.php), I'm not sure but I think it might be a part of the latest OpenCV.

Comment: It uses functionality from OpenCV, based on the Ferns library.